# Why hidden symbols are still added to DSO

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

```
user@pc ~/hiddensymbols
% cat main.cpp 
__attribute__((visibility ("hidden"))) int f_b1(void){
return 21 ;
}

__attribute__((visibility ("hidden"))) int f_b3(void){
return f_b1() ;
}                                                                                                                                    user@pc ~/hiddensymbols
 % g++ -shared main.cpp
user@pc ~/hiddensymbols
 % nm -C ./a.out       
.............
000000000000055a t f_b1()
0000000000000565 t f_b3()
```

I wonder, what was the point in leaving these two symbols in DSO? I understand that dynamic linker can't use them, but then why they are added to some hidden symbol table? What was the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the linker emits an object file it records the name and the address of each symbol, regardless of its visibility (in `.symtab` section which you can dump with `readelf --symbols <elf-file>` ). It is used for debugging to display symbol names even if no debug information is available. During normal execution this section is not loaded/mapped into the address space.

Hidden symbols cannot be used to resolve symbols from other object files, just like symbols marked with `static` keyword. You can strip them out with `strip` utility if necessary.

Comment: But here it leaves these symbols in shared library, it doesn't keep any useful information for runtime.

Comment: @IbraimGaniev These symbols are used for debugging to display symbol names even if no debug information is available.